# How to set Basic Auth (Usernama and password) using java code

Tags: java

currently i am setting as below:

```
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic NDUwNjMyOTc6U2hyaXNo2weQDEy");
```

`Basic NDUwNjMyOTc6U2hyaXNo2weQDEy"----------`This part i have generated using postman. but it contains `user` name and `password`.

How to generate this Auth `Basic NDUwNjMyOTc6U2hyaXNo2weQDEy` using java and pass it in `setRequestProperty`.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using rest assured

Comment: @WilfredClement no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic auth header is generated from `username:password` using base 64,
the header authorization value could be generated like so:

```
Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
String originalString = username+":"+password;
String encodedString = encoder.encodeToString(originalString.getBytes());

String headerAthorization="Basic "+encodedString;
```

Comment: @M.Ismain have update as below but still its not working:                                                          
                        Encoder encoder = Base64.getEncoder();
   String originalString = name+":"+password;
   String encodedString = encoder.encodeToString(originalString.getBytes());

   String headerAthorization="basic "+encodedString;
   connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", headerAthorization);

Comment: @Routray what is the error exactly? the word basic should not be case-sensitive, try with Basic instead of basic.

Comment: @Ismail, thanks for identifying my mistake...now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

You add header `Basic ENCODED`, where the encoded is base64 of `"user:password"`.
See https://github.com/jcabi/jcabi-http/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jcabi/http/wire/BasicAuthWire.java#L123 for example.